# Какие способы рисования простых двумерных фигур (окружность, квадрат и т.п.) существуют в C++?

Tags: c++

Какие способы рисования простых двумерных фигур (окружность, квадрат и т.п.) существуют в C++ ?

Comment: Нужны подробности: на каком устройстве рисовать, в какой ОС и так далее. Иначе тут сочинение страниц на 100 можно написать...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

В стандарте языка никаких графических средств нет.

В зависимости от операционной системы, используемой библиотеки и т.д  способы могут быть самыми разными, но все они выходят за рамки стандартного C++.

Comment: ну вот в билдере же можно как то

Comment: @ivanvae Можно практически любым компилятором. Но - НЕ СРЕДСТВАМИ C++, а средствами операционной системы. Есть более-менее переносимые библиотеки графических интерфейсов типа FLTK, но это - не стандартное средство C++.

Comment: А какая самая простая библиотека для windows ?

Comment: как ни дико звучит но мне встроенная в borland c понравилась, но для неё нужно видео драйвер положить иногда.

Comment: @ivanvae Страуструп в своей книге "Программирование. Принципы и практика с использованием C++" рекомендует FLTK, она у него там описана, почему я ее и вспомнил...

Comment: FLTK больше для интерфейса, готовые кнопочки там, поля ввода и так далее. Для рисования я бы предложил SDL (оформил данную рекомендацию ответом): работает на уйме платформ, достаточно проста для простых применений можно найти кучу примеров использования.

Answer (score 3):

Возьмите [SDL2](https://www.libsdl.org/). Не смотрите, что там скрины игрушек, сама библиотека для базовых целей очень проста (вывести окно, нарисровать линию, прямоугольник и так далее). Вот [тут](http://wiki.libsdl.org/FrontPage) полно сслок на документацию, книги, руководства.

Вот несколько ссылок, что бы освоиться:

- http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/ - набор уроков от простого к сложному
- https://habrahabr.ru/post/201392/ - простое введение
- https://habrahabr.ru/post/198600/ - начало цикла уроков (хотя там, вроде только два и получилось у автора сделать)

Стандартных же средств языка для этого не существует. Ровно как и (пока?) стандартных средств для работы с сетью или файловой системой (будет с C++17).

Вот, кстати, пробы ради портировал на SDL простую игрушку для KolibriOS: https://github.com/h4tr3d/laser-tank. Основная работа с SDL сосредоточена [тут](https://github.com/h4tr3d/laser-tank/blob/master/platform/sdl2/kosSyst.cpp).

Другим вариантом, которым я однажды пользовался оказался [CImg](http://cimg.eu). Плюс библиотеки в её феноменальной простоте установке: она состоит из одного заголовочного файла. Работает на достаточном числе платформ и компиляторах, предоставляя унифицированный интерфейс к системным функциям. Начать знакомство можно с [этого](http://cimg.eu/reference/group__cimg__tutorial.html) простого туториала. А законченный пример с рисрованием линии, окружности и прямоугольника будет таким:

```
#include "CImg.h"
using namespace cimg_library;

int main() 
{
    CImg<unsigned char> visu(500,400,1,3,0);
    const unsigned char red[]   = { 255,0,0 },
                        green[] = { 0,255,0 },
                        blue[]  = { 0,0,255 };

    CImgDisplay draw_disp(visu, "Drawing sample");

    while (!draw_disp.is_closed())
    {
        visu.draw_line(40, 40, 80, 70, red);
        visu.draw_circle(150, 150, 50, green);
        visu.draw_rectangle(210, 120, 300, 240, blue);
        visu.display(draw_disp);
        draw_disp.wait();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

На Linux собирать так:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -lX11 -pthread
```

А вообще, вот вам ещё, можно сказать, официальный, список библиотек, выбирайте:

- http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать иные графические библиотеки под эту задачу. 
Например, SDL2 или SFML. 
Эти графические библиотеки вполне способны выполнить Вашу задачу. 
Так же есть вариант использования glut, либо другую иной библиотеку совместимую с OpenGL.